# Plot Histogram with Points Instead of Bars

Tags: r, plot, histogram

Here is a question for R-users. I am interested in drawing a histogram with points stacked up, instead of a bar. For example if the data is (1,1,2,1,2,3,3,3,4,4), then I would like to see three points stacked up at 1, 2 points stacked up at 2 and so on. What is the best way to do this in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Greg Snow's TeachingDemos package contains a [dots(x, ...)](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/TeachingDemos/docs/dots) function which seems to fit your need:

```
dots( round( rnorm(50, 10,3) ) )
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to be the simplest of all solutions!! Thanks Kyubic

Comment: @Ramnath: When you look at the source code it basically does the same as Jonathan Chang's answer

Answer (score 6):

You can do this yourself pretty quickly:

```
x <- c(1,1,2,1,2,3,3,3,4,4)
plot(sort(x), sequence(table(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. This does the job for me!

Answer (score 6):

The simplest answer I know is this:

```
x <- c(1,1,2,1,2,3,3,3,4,4)
stripchart(x,method="stack",at=0)
```

It's better than Jonathan Chang's suggestion because `stripchart` does proper stacking of points.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Stripchart seems very intuitive, although I would prefer the stack of points to be separate.

Answer (score 2):

Another easy way would be:

```
x <- c(1,1,2,1,2,3,3,3,4,4)
myhist <- hist(x)
myhistX <- myhist$mids
myhistY <- myhist$density
```

And now you can plot it in any way you like:

```
plot(myhistY~myhistX)
```

This way you can change the stacking options when building a "histogram" object.