# dotplot dot not showing up and format of dot plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, mosaic-plot

How can I show the dots colored using the mosaic package to do a dotplot?

```
library(mosaic)
n=500
r =rnorm(n)
d = data.frame( x = sample(r ,n= 1,size = n, replace = TRUE), color = c(rep("red",n/2), rep("green",n/2)))
dotPlot(d$x,breaks = seq(min(d$x)-.1,max(d$x)+.1,.1))
```

right now all the dots are blue but I would like them to be colored according to the color column inthe data table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `stackgroups=TRUE` so that the two different colors aren't plotted on top of each other.

```
n=20
set.seed(15)
d = data.frame(x = sample(seq(1,10,1), n, replace = TRUE), 
               color = c(rep("red",n/2), rep("green",n/2)))
table(d$x[order(d$x)])
length(d$x[order(d$x)])
binwidth= 1

ggplot(d, aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_dotplot(breaks = seq(0.5,10.5,1), binwidth = binwidth, 
               method="histodot", aes(fill = color),
               stackgroups=TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:10)
```

Also, ggplot uses its internal color palette for the fill aesthetic. You'd get the same colors regardless of what you called the values of the "color" column in your data. Add `scale_fill_manual(values=c("green","red"))` if you want to set the colors manually.

[image]

Comment: Thank you that seems to have solved problem 1. Can you help with the other 2 issues? If I change n = 200 the dots don't appear and the y axis is not the count. I need to dynamically change the yaxis limit I think

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure why that's happening, but I see now that the y-axis ticks are not actually counts. I'll see if I can figure out what's going on.

Comment: The y-scale is a [known issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16216666/496488) with `geom_dotplot`.

Comment: yes it is known issue but you can scale it by using ylim() to see the counts. se how they use ylim here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216312/how-to-plot-stacked-point-histograms-in-ggplot2-in-r

Comment: `ylim` (or `scale_y_continuous`) changes the labels on the y-axis, but those labels don't correspond to the number of dots.

Comment: I think there has to be a combination of the dotsize parameter, binwidth and ylim that will make it look good

Comment: It looks like the only way to fit all the dots is to decrease the dot size. This is essentially what ggplot would have to do to fit all the dots even if `ylim()` worked as expected. I suggest you post a question to the ggplot2 googlegroup and see if anyone there has a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

If you are still interested in a `mosaic`/`lattice` solution rather than a `ggplot2` solution, here you go.

```
dotPlot( ~ x, data = d, width = 0.1, groups = color, 
  par.settings=list(superpose.symbol = list(pch = 16, col=c("green", "red"))))
```

[resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLfIE.png)

Notice also

- as with `ggplot2`, the colors are not determined by the values in your `color` variable but by the theme.  You can use `par.settings` to modify this on the level of a plot or `trellis.par.set()` to change the defaults.
- it is preferable to use a formula and `data =` and to avoid the `$` operator.
- you can use the `width` argument rather than `breaks` if you want to set the bin width.  (You can use the `center` argument to control the centers of the bins if that matters to you.  By default, 0 will be the center of a bin.)